# How do nonlinear speedometers work?

Tags: speedometer

Some cars, now have nonlinear speedometers. How can they achieve to get different spacing between some speed ranges?

For better understanding, see the image

[image]

of an old Audi A4 speedometer.

The range from 70 to 100 is not linear, because there are equally spaced marks, as you can see in the table:

```
Mark        Increment from previous
  70               5 (was 65, not shown on this table)
  75               5 
  80               5 
  90              10
 100              10
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? Can you explain what you mean by "spacing"?

Comment: I expect the answer will be signal processing. Rather than display the speed which corresponds to the voltage output of the speed sensor, run it through a piecewise function

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Something like [this](http://www.need4speed.ws/images/uploads/speed/phaeton275.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The speedo will be a standard linear voltmeter.

Vehicle speed sensors are usually attached to either the gearbox output or the differential and produce a pulsed output at a frequency proportional to the vehicle speed.

On a 'normal' speedo, the ECU will read the pulses from the speed sensor and produce a linear voltage proportional to the vehicle speed to send to the speedo.

With this non-linear speedo, the ECU simply creates a non-linear voltage range that fits with the graduations on the speedo.  This is a very simple task to perform in software.